Image Wrapped full 3D Mesh
I don't want to wrap the full mesh.
How can embed the image on 3D Tshirt mesh.
Here is my 3D Tshirt UV Map.

Here is my 3D Tshirt Mesh Output
The image wrap full mesh as you see here.

The uploaded Image:

The full output of the problem:

Here is my code:
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

function App() {
  const threeCanvasRef = useRef(null);
  const uvCanvasRef = useRef(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef(null);
  const scene = useRef(null);
  const imagePlaneRef = useRef(null); // Ref for the image plane (not used in this implementation)
  const tShirtMeshRef = useRef(null); // Reference to the t-shirt mesh
  const [uploadedImage, setUploadedImage] = useState(null);

   const [imagePosition, setImagePosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [imageScale, setImageScale] = useState({ x: 1, y: 1 });
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Scene setup
    scene.current = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.current.background = new THREE.Color(0x333);

    // Camera setup
    cameraRef.current = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 0.1, 1000); // Adjust aspect ratio as needed
    cameraRef.current.position.z = 150; // Adjusted camera position

    // Renderer setup (for the 3D scene)
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight); // Half the screen width
    renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
    renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    // OrbitControls setup
    const controls = new OrbitControls(cameraRef.current, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.15;

    // Lights
    const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
    hemiLight.position.set(0, 200, 0);
    scene.current.add(hemiLight);

    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    dirLight.position.set(0, 200, 100);
    dirLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.current.add(dirLight);

    // Load the GLTF model
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/assets/tshirt.glb', (gltf) => {
      scene.current.remove(scene.current.getObjectByName('mesh3d'));
      gltf.scene.name = 'mesh3d';
      gltf.scene.traverse(child => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
          tShirtMeshRef.current = child; // Assuming the first mesh is the t-shirt
          drawUVMap(child); // Draw UVs of the first mesh

          if (uploadedImage) {
            applyImageToMesh(uploadedImage);
          }
        }
      });
      scene.current.add(gltf.scene);
      renderer.render(scene.current, cameraRef.current);
      if (threeCanvasRef.current.children.length > 0) {
        threeCanvasRef.current.removeChild(threeCanvasRef.current.children[0]);
      }
      threeCanvasRef.current.append(renderer.domElement);
    }, undefined, (error) => {
      console.error('Error loading GLTF file:', error);
    });

    // Resize handling
    const updateRendererSize = () => {
      const width = threeCanvasRef.current.clientWidth;
      const height = threeCanvasRef.current.clientHeight;
      renderer.setSize(width, height);
      cameraRef.current.aspect = width / height;
      cameraRef.current.updateProjectionMatrix();
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', updateRendererSize);
    updateRendererSize(); // Call on initial load

    // Animation loop
    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene.current, cameraRef.current);
    };

    animate();

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', updateRendererSize);
      renderer.dispose();
      controls.dispose();
      scene.current.clear();
    };
  }, [uploadedImage]);

  // Handle image upload
  // Handle image upload
  const handleImageUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    setUploadedImage(imageUrl);

    // Draw the uploaded image on the UV canvas
    drawImageOnUVCanvas(imageUrl);

    // Apply the image to the mesh (this will be updated based on imagePosition and imageScale)
    applyImageToMesh(imageUrl);
  };


  const drawImageOnUVCanvas = (imageUrl) => {
    const uvCanvas = uvCanvasRef.current;
    const ctx = uvCanvas.getContext('2d');

    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const aspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
      let width = uvCanvas.width;
      let height = uvCanvas.height;

      if (aspectRatio > 1) {
        height = width / aspectRatio;
      } else {
        width = height * aspectRatio;
      }

      // Draw the image in the center
      ctx.drawImage(img, (uvCanvas.width - width) / 2, (uvCanvas.height - height) / 2, width, height);
    };
    img.src = imageUrl;
  };
  // Apply the image to the mesh
  const applyImageToMesh = (imageUrl) => {
    if (tShirtMeshRef.current) {
      const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(imageUrl);
      texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
      texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
      tShirtMeshRef.current.material.map = texture;
      tShirtMeshRef.current.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  };


  const handleMouseDown = (event) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (!isDragging || !uploadedImage) return; 

    const uvCanvas = uvCanvasRef.current;
    const rect = uvCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // Calculate image position and scale based on mouse position
    const newImagePosition = { x: mouseX / uvCanvas.width, y: 1 - (mouseY / uvCanvas.height) };
    setImagePosition(newImagePosition); 

    // Update the texture on the mesh
    if (tShirtMeshRef.current && tShirtMeshRef.current.material.map) {
      const texture = tShirtMeshRef.current.material.map;

      // Adjust these values to control scaling behavior
      const scaleFactorX = 2; 
      const scaleFactorY = 2; 

      texture.repeat.set(imageScale.x * scaleFactorX, imageScale.y * scaleFactorY);
      texture.offset.set(newImagePosition.x, newImagePosition.y);
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
    }
  };


  // Function to draw the UV map on a separate canvas
  const drawUVMap = (mesh) => {
    const uvCanvas = uvCanvasRef.current;
    const ctx = uvCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const uvAttribute = mesh.geometry.attributes.uv;

    const canvasWidth = uvCanvas.width;
    const canvasHeight = uvCanvas.height;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    for (let i = 0; i < uvAttribute.count; i += 3) {
      const u = uvAttribute.getX(i);
      const v = uvAttribute.getY(i);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.fillRect(u * canvasWidth, (1 - v) * canvasHeight, 2, 2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app" style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      <div
        id="canvas-container"
        ref={threeCanvasRef}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100vh',
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      />
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: '0',
      }}>
        <div className="controls">
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageUpload} />
        </div>
        <canvas
          ref={uvCanvasRef}
          width={window.innerWidth / 2}
          height={window.innerHeight / 2}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
          onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
          onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
          style={{ border: '1px solid black', cursor: 'grab' }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Don't want to wrap the full mesh.
The image should be on its original dimension.
